# Error Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input*

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-1.12.4.js:9011)
at Object.success (script.js:19)
at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

Перегулил что смог - решения проблемы не нашел. Понял что не может передать запрос почему-то, но, почему - не понял.

```
$.ajax( {
    url: '/' + url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: name + '_f=1' + str,
    cache: false,
    success: function( result ) {

        obj = jQuery.parseJSON( result ); // Комментарий

        if ( obj.go ) go(obj.go);
        else alert( obj.message );
    }

} );
```

ошИбиться при выполнении следующего кода:

```
    if ( $_SESSION['confirm']['type'] == 'registration' ) {

        if ( $_SESSION['confirm']['code'] != $_POST['code'] ) {
            message('Код подтверждения регистрации указан неверно!');

            mysqli_query($connect, 'INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ("", "'.$_SESSION['confirm']['email'].'", "'.$_SESSION['confirm']['password'].'")');
            unset($_SESSION['confirm']);

            go('login');
        }

    } else not_found();
```

А конкретно при запросе в БД - запись в БД не создает, функцию 'go'(редирект) не выполняет.

Comment: Это всё интересно, но самого главного нет: что приходит в качестве ответа из обработчика `POST`?

Comment: $_SESSION['confirm']['code'] -> выводит код, а $_POST['code'] -> пустой... При вводе правильного кода из сессии - выдаёт эту ошибку, видимо не что-то с POST запросом.

Comment: Проблему решил.

Answer (score 0):

1. В ajax запросе нигде не указана переменная code. Если Я правильно понимаю, то это скорее всего должно быть как-то так:

   ```
   $.ajax( {
     url: '/' + url,
     type: 'POST',
     data: ({ code : name + '_f=1' + str }), // Должна передаваться переменная.
     cache: false,
     success: function( result ) {

       obj = jQuery.parseJSON( result );

       if ( obj.go ) go(obj.go);
       else alert( obj.message );
     }

   } );
   ```
2. Твой код, куда приходит запрос, должен возвращать что-то в json. К примеру

   ```
   die(json_encode(['status'=>'ok']));
   ```

И не должен делать никаких редиректов и выводить других сообщений.

P.S. Советую всегда выводить в консоль переменную, которая приходит в success. Тогда есть вероятность, что ты поймешь в чем суть ошибки, ведь если PHP вывел ошибку, то именно текст ошибки мог вернуться тебе в JS.

P.P.S Тебе стоит еще немного подучить AJAX, к примеру уроки от Ruseller. На его сайте куча полезных вещей для разработчика.